# React component hosted on S3, behind paywall/authentication

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to write a React component which will be included on a third party website, but I want that only some websites to be able to use it (they will pay to use it). The website will allow their logged in users to interact with my React component.
The component will be hosted on AWS S3.
I'm bit blocked, it seems neither AWS Cognito or STS can provide me what I want, but I might be missing something. Another solution would be be to use an IAM role, but the website (at least the first one that's going to use my component) has only email authentication for it's users, no SAML2 or OpenID implementation.

Any ideas how can I be sure, that only websites I give access can use the component?

Comment: A React Component is just a bunch of javascript. what exactly do you mean by access in this case?

Comment: @azium Access means, that I want to restrict the usage of the component only to certain websites.

Comment: What does "usage" mean though? Do you mean the ability to load the javascript onto the page? restrict api calls or something? is this component being loaded in an iframe that obscures loading of the component source unless the parent domain matches something in your databases or something?

Comment: do you happen to have an example of something hidden behind a paywall in the way you're imagining - that might help to understand what you mean a little better

Comment: by what means is the website developer able to use your component in the first place? is it an npm package?

Comment: @azium yes, I want to restrict the ability to even load the script. Even if they add it to the webpage, it should render an empty <div></div> if the webpage it's being loaded on isn't authenticated.